# Set aspnetcore_environment within build configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-config, teamcity

I have simple asp.net core project. I want to deploy it via TeamCity to IIS.
The problem is that I can't setup ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT when publishing the project.
My goal is to use default behaviour to load appsettings files:

```
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
```

I use .csproj instead of project.json and Web.config's section related to configuration looks like:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'prod-zone-a|AnyCPU' ">
    <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;NETCOREAPP1_1</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Publish is executed like:

```
dotnet publish --configuration prod-zone-a --output <some-dir>
```

Also it's necessary to have several site on IIS published with different configurations: prod-zone-a, prod-zone-b, etc (corresponded appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json looks different too)

How can I implement such idea?
Or probably I should to throw this idea out and follow another way?

**Update:**

According to [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments) I've added separate build step to TeamCity (powershell command):

```
$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "prod-zone-a"
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Haven't worked w/ team city in a while but you need to execute: ```set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=prod-zone-a``` via a command line task BEFORE 'dotnet publish'.  Then you need to make sure that you have the applicabale 'appsettings.prod-zone-a.json' file as part of your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found (quite different to this question) is to use web.config transformations [that way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43103044/set-web-config-transform-in-asp-net-core) (another my question on SO)

The main reason is that it's necessary not just publish the project with necessary ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value, but this value is also needed in application runtime on IIS