# Set web.config transform in Asp.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, web.config-transform

I've just came across with problem of web.config transformation in asp.net core.

There are two files: base web.config and web.prod-zone-a.config. My aim is to use transformation inside web.prod-zone-a.config when publishing my project.
I have the following "prod-zone-a" configuration settings in .csproj:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'prod-zone-a|AnyCPU' ">
    <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;NETCOREAPP1_1</DefineConstants>
    <Configuration>prod-zone-a</Configuration>
</PropertyGroup>
```

web.prod-zone-a.config looks like:

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore>
        <environmentVariables xdt:Transform="Replace">
            <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="prod-zone-a" />
        </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
</system.webServer>
```

I tried to run publish by two commands:

```
dotnet msbuild /t:Publish /p:OutputPath=c:\delivery /p:Configuration=prod-zone-a
```

and

```
dotnet publish --configuration prod-zone-a --output c:\delivery
```

But no transformation applies to web.config on output - just the default value.
Do I miss something in configuration or command executing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a well-documented [tool on github](https://github.com/nil4/dotnet-transform-xdt#msbuild) for xdt-transformations.
Also it doesn't depend on command, both of `dotnet publish` and `dotnet msbuild` works fine

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me:

1. Add `web.release.config` file to the project root.
2. In Visual Studio 2017, Publish using Web Deploy (make sure it is set to Release). Settings will automatically be picked up.

Sample transformation:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
        <system.webServer>
          <aspNetCore>
            <environmentVariables>
              <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="PRODUCTION" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" />
            </environmentVariables>
          </aspNetCore>
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Update: If you want to remove `web.config.release` file and others on publish, simply edit your **.csproj** file and add something like this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="appsettings.Development.json" />
    <Content Remove="web.release.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="appsettings.Development.json" />
    <None Include="web.release.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to add an additional <location> tag in between <configuration> and <system.webServer> tags to match the config format for project template "ASP.NET Core Web Application".

Comment: Thank you for the sample transformation, works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks, but web.Release.config is still there after publish :( any legit way to get rid of it?

Comment: @DmitryGusarov - I have added some code for your specific problem.

Comment: Be sure that IsTransformWebConfigDisabled is set to false in csproj file if this does not work.

Answer (score 5):

With the latest version of dotnet cli (2.1.400 or greater), you can just set this msbuild property $(EnvironmentName) and publish tooling will take care of adding ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environmentVariable to the web.config with the specified environment name.

Also, XDT support is available starting 2.2.100-preview1.

Sample: https://github.com/vijayrkn/webconfigtransform/blob/master/README.md

Comment: With the current version 2.2 works perfectly to add ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT using:`dotnet publish (projectlocation) /p:EnvironmentName=PreProduction`

Answer (score 2):

Following on from user1820686's answer above:

The github page misses out some of the steps required to add this for MSBuild/csproj tooling:

You need to open a command prompt in your project directory and run

```
dotnet add myProj.csproj package Microsoft.DotNet.Xdt.Tools --version 2.0.0
```

Then you need to open the csproj file and add

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Dotnet.Xdt.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <!-- ... other package references ... -->
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

IIS Web Deploy ASP.NET Core (2.1) in Visual Studio 2017 (VS2017)

First do this: (ref:https://github.com/nil4/dotnet-transform-xdt#-use-with-msbuildcsproj-tooling)

1. Install package - `dotnet add package DotNet.Xdt --version 2.1.0`
2. Modify .csproj - add package - refer github
3. Modify .csproj - add transform code (`ApplyXdtConfigTransform`) at the end - refer github
4. Add `web.DEV_Server.config` transfor file by right-clicking on `DEV_Server.pubxml`
5. Added following to `web.DEV_Server.config`

`<environmentVariable xdt:Locator="Match(name)" name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" />`

6. Modify `DEV_Server.pubxml` to modify following setting value.

`<LastUsedBuildConfiguration>DEV_Server</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>`

7. Validate Connection & Publish

Deploy still uploads other config files, not sure how to stop that.

Answer (score 1):

may be i don't clear question. For mine case web.config override all settings in web.Release.config file.

Fix for me, i just add reference for transformation `xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" to configuration` file.

so, .config file should start:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
```

After some time, the best solutions is using [dotnet-transform-xdt tool](https://github.com/nil4/dotnet-transform-xdt#msbuild)

Answer (score 1):

This is now supported by `dotnet publish` from SDK version 2.2 with a whole bunch of options.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/transform-webconfig?view=aspnetcore-2.2

I think in the example from the question, it would then work when published as

`dotnet publish --configuration prod-zone-a`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me with the 1. & 2. above:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <location>
    <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"
                  xdt:Locator="Match(existingResponse)"
                  xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```